# How to attach a base64 png image in the slack bot's response?

Tags: base64, slack, slack-api

This is the documentation for Slack's bot response: https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting

Is there any way to pass in an base64 image string which appears as an image in Slack?

I tried using passing the base64 string in the image_url field of the attachment. It doesn't seem to work.

```
  const data = {
    "response_type": "in_channel",
    "text": "Hello, your QR code is",
    "attachments": [
        { 
          "image_url": "data:image/png;base64,..."
        }
      ]
    }
  res.send(data);
```

I'm expecting the image encoded by the base64 string to show up as message in Slack.

Comment: ^^ that is the only way. Also base64 encoded images do not work.